# There is no Keyboard Layout Options in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, keyboard-layout

After updating the packages in **Linux Mint 19.3** I lost the **keyboard settings** .

Linux **Language switching** shortcut didn't work anymore.

I went to **system settings** to define new shortcuts but ***NO*** options to do that .

What should I do to solve this problem ?

See the picture below , There is ***NO Keyboard Layout Options*** !

[image]

And This is my system information :
[image]

I tested in **Mate** and **Cinnamon** Desktop .

Comment: Keyboard model: "Unknown" should be a clue for you ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes , but i don't know what happened after update packages and My keyboard is okay in another systems

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. the "dconf" folder in the following path was the incorrect owner.

```
/home/[user name]/.cache/dconf
```

The owner of the folder was "root" user. I change it to the user that login with it and problem solved.

P.S: After change ownership log out and login again.